# How to preload SVG in Ionic view?

Tags: angularjs, svg, ionic-framework

I built a mobile app with Ionic and on one of my views I have an SVG image of 202KB

The problem is that it takes very long to load that view/page. It takes up to 3-4 seconds load and display the view. Is there any way to load svg faster?

I tried to add svg and html view to Cache in advance:

```
$ionicTemplateCache('img/image.svg');
$ionicTemplateCache('views/maps.html');
```

I also tried a preload factory that loads images in advance but that didn't help either.

```
var img = ['image.svg'];

//load all the images
preloader.preloadImages( imgs ).then(function() {
  // Loading was successful.
  console.log(" Loading was successful.");
}, function() {
  // Loading failed on at least one image.
  console.log("Loading failed on at least one image.");
});
```

Below is how my app looks like:

Angular directive which is the svg image:

```
app.directive('svgMap', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'img/image.svg'
    }
}]);
```

maps.html where the svg image is loaded

```
<svg-map></svg-map>
```

So, when I go to maps.html it takes very long to load.

Answer (score 0):

In preloader you're calling `.preloadImages( imgs )` but your image is in `var img`. Also, try to gzip you svg on the server-side (if not yet).